# Shuf command in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shuffle

I am confused with how *shuf* command works with streaming input. Does it buffer the data? Or is there some way of doing this in an online fashion.

Comment: Well, good that `shuf` is opensource. So just [inspect the source](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/shuf.c). It works somewhat "intelligently" - the next line could be read, could be ignored, it all depends. But in general cases, yes, the whole input has to be buffered.

Comment: Thanks for the response, so if i understand it correctly in cases when we are selecting some k items from the input it samples using reservoir sampling, so doesn't need to keep it in memory  but if we are shuffling the whole file it would need to keeping the whole data in memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This tool reads either a file, or from the linux/unix stdin. There is no streaming.

When you do just do `shuf` on the command line, you will have to press CTRL-D at some point to tell it "input is complete". Only then the tool starts processing the data.